# Vite Typescript for React 17

Tags: reactjs, typescript, frontend, vite

Is there any way to install **Vite** and **Typescript** for **React 17** instead of **18**? We are using React 17.0.2 at work and considering to move Typescript.

Comment: Yes, there shouldn't be any issues

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was not able to find a command to do so using vite cli, but you can switch to react 17 manually without trouble. After creating a Vite react project, inside you have to first install older react version:

```
npm i react@17 react-dom@17
```

And also when using typescript:

```
npm i -D @types/react@17 @types/react-dom@17
```

Then since React 18 uses new method to render into document, you also need to change `main.jsx` or `main.tsx` to use old `render` method:

```
...
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
...

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Then you should be good to go.

Comment: thank you @zithir, this i found this useful today